# How can a script add a little icon overlay on files' icons

Tags: windows-7, batch, icons

Just like Dropbox does, I'd like to show if a file is backed up using the icon overlay. How could this be done, without human intervention and regarding a specific computer so it doesn't have to be distributable.

This question regards only how to add/change this icon small overlay, not how to check if the files are backed up.

I am aiming at Windows 7 at the moment.

Comment: [Icons and Icon Overlays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521690(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Thx @Seth, I'll take a look on how to achieve it.

Comment: My guess would be because it's not really that [good of a question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You didn't include much/any information on what you've tried or what your research so far showed. Though a plus is that you narrowed it down a bit. Depending on how you approach this question (see also the reference I linked) you might be better of asking on Stackoverflow if you need to ask about specific code. I didn't vote so it's just my guess.

Comment: I was more interested in the knowledge than the implementation (which I'm gonna do myself), so superuser it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the reference [Icons and Icon Overlays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521690(v=vs.85).aspx) or more specifically [How to Create Icon Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122(v=vs.85).aspx) and [How to Implement Icon Overlay Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127442(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see that you need to implement a DLL/COM Component.

Said DLL needs to implement certain interfaces (`IUnknown` and `IShellIconOverlayIdentifier` as far as I can tell) and will be called by the Windows explorer process upon displaying an icon. For this to happen you need to create an entry in the registry. As you probably want that overlay to be displayed for all types of files you will probably need to register for a general file type.

Later on `GetOverlayInfo` will be called to register your icon and `IsMemberOf` to indicate whenever or not you want your overlay to be displayed.

As for identifying files or storing information about them you could use an [Alternate Data Stream](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/07/introduction-to-alternate-data-streams/) though that would mean it would only/mostly work for NTFS and as you said is not really part of your question.

If you look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/154) help article for DropBox you will see that the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` could/would also be important in order to decide which icons are going to be displayed.